# Split double new lines in platform independent manner

Tags: python, string, newline

i need to to following in platform independent way:

```
1) read the file with using codecs.open() (for utf-8)
2) split lines according to two new lines.
3) split entities according to new line
```

example input:

```
1) FIRST UTF-8 ENTITY ŞŞŞŞ\n 
2) SECOND ELEMENT OF FIRST ENTITY\n 
\n\n 
1) SECOND ENTITIY\n
2) SECOND ELEMENT OF SECOND ENTITIY\n
```

after reading file, string.split('\n\n') works in mac osx, but it does not seem platform independent way of handling this (file might be prepared on another os).

i know that string.splitlines() works platform independent but how to split two new lines between entities in platform independent way?

edit: file might be prepared on any platform, thus might have any kind of line endings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 main types of separators which in use currently: `\n` - unices and `\r\n` - windows (`\r` was used on old mac os and it is almost not used now)

Simple solution is to replace `\r` with empty string and after that use only `\n`. If you want to support `\r` then check that `\n` is not exists in string and replace all `\r` to `\n`.

Next code converts `\r\n` `\n\r` `\n` `\r` variants to `\n`:

```
if "\n" in data:
    data = data.replace("\r", "")
else:
    data = data.replace("\r", "\n")
```

Comment: it works appereantly, i was hoping to handle this situation within python modules but this also works well, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Python has a built-in tool to deal with this: `os.linesep`. So you can use :

```
string.split(2*os.linesep)
```

Open the text file using the Universal mode.

```
codecs.open(filename, 'U')
```

Comment: what if i do not know on which platform the file is prepared? For example, file is prepared on windows and i could be able to parse in on osx?